# Erlang: exit/shutdown synchronous or asynchronous?

Tags: asynchronous, process, erlang, signals, synchronous

You have a process tree you want to kill, so you send an exit(PID, shutdown) to the supervisor.  There's other stuff you need to do, but it can't be done until this process tree is shutdown.  For instance, let's say this process tree writes to a database.  You want to shut everything down cleanly.  You want to shut down the database, but obviously you need to shut down the process tree first, else the tree could be in the middle of a write to the database.

My question is, when I send the exit signal, is it synchronous or asynchronous?  If it is synchronous, it seems I have no worries, but if it is asynchronous, I will need to do something like establish a process monitor and check whether the tree shut down before I proceed with database shutdown, correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: OTP shutdown is synchronous. exit/2 is a single asynchronous message.

Long answer: All messages in Erlang are asynchronous. The shutdown message is no different. However, there is more to **shutdown** than just sending a message. The supervisor listens for `{'DOWN', ...}` messages after sending the exit signal. Only after it receives a 'DOWN' message or times out does it proceed, so in effect it is synchronous. Checkout the supervisor source code. On line 894 is where the functions that actually makes the exit call is defined:

```
shutdown(Pid, Time) ->
case monitor_child(Pid) of
ok ->
    exit(Pid, shutdown), %% Try to shutdown gracefully
    receive 
    {'DOWN', _MRef, process, Pid, shutdown} ->
        ok;
    {'DOWN', _MRef, process, Pid, OtherReason} ->
        {error, OtherReason}
    after Time ->
        exit(Pid, kill),  %% Force termination.
        receive
        {'DOWN', _MRef, process, Pid, OtherReason} ->
            {error, OtherReason}
        end
    end;
{error, Reason} ->      
    {error, Reason}
end.
```

The source code can be viewed on GitHub here: https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/stdlib/src/supervisor.erl#L894

`erlang:exit/2` calls on the other hand is simply an asynchronous exit signal

Comment: But what if I'm trying to shutdown the supervisor by sending the asynch exit signal?  That's how it's supposed to be done, right?  So it seems I have to treat this thing as asynch and wait until shutdown has been verified before proceeding, correct?

Comment: Well that supervisor should be supervised by another supervisor, unless it is the top supervisor in your supervision tree. If it is the top supervisor in the tree, the application behavior should handle shutdown. You shouldn't need to call exit/2 on it.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to manage this yourself, do your own monitoring:

```
sneak_attack(BankGuard) ->
    monitor(process, BankGuard),
    exit(BankGuard, kill),
    Cash = receive {'DOWN', _, process, BankGuard, _} -> rob_bank() end,
    send_to_bahamas(Cash).
```

In this example rob_bank() and anything after is blocked waiting on the `'DOWN'` message from BankGuard.

Also, note that this is a much more general concept than just shutting something down. All messages in Erlang are asynchronous but unlike UDP, ordering (between two processes) and delivery (so long as the destination is alive) is guaranteed. So synchronous messaging is simply monitoring the target, sending a tagged message, and blocking on receipt of the return message.